# store data from input form to var for javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am learning javascript right now.
so I want to make a function that converts fahrenheit to celsius but with an input to store in variable and then shows the result with `alert(result);`

here's my code from my basic understanding

```js
var f = document.getElementById("fa").value;

function toCelsius(f) {
  var result = (5/9) * (f-32);
  alert (result);
}
```

```html
<p>calls a function to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius:</p>
<form>
  input fahrenheit :<input type="number" id="fa">
  <button onclick="toCelsius(f)">submit</button>
</form>
```

everytime I input a number, the result does not change, I assume I'm wrong in .value or .innerHTML ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the variable, 'f' in your mathematical expression as a number. JavaScript will do type juggling for you, but since you are learning, it is good to know that there is a way to force it.

```
  function toCelsius() 
  {

       var f = parseFloat(document.getElementById("fa").value);
       var result = (5/9) * (f-32);
       alert (result);
  }
```

or

```
  function toCelsius() 
  {
       var result = (5/9) * (parseFloat(document.getElementById("fa").value) - 32);
       alert (result);
  }
```

or

```
  function toCelsius() 
  {
       alert ((5/9) * (parseFloat(document.getElementById("fa").value) - 32));
  }
```

=========

```
  <button onclick="toCelsius(f)">submit</button>
```

This won't work because f is not in play at this time.
Call your handler, then grab the DOM values you need.

Comment: so just because the input type is number, that does not mean the value is a number but a string, and parseFloat changes the value type from string into number.

thank you that was good

Comment: As they say in Full House, "You got it dude!" All values grabbed from the DOM are strings. To do mathematical operations, you must perform explicit, or implicit, type conversion to a number. All numbers in JavaScript are 64-bit float values. Thus, there is also a parseInt, but that simply performs truncation (or rounding, I forget) on the decimal part.

Comment: Note that in this case, the fact that *f* is a string is irrelevant since the minus operator `-` will coerce it to number anyway, so this answer doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @Rob, that is a non-coherent comment. Just because implicit type conversion will make JavaScript convert the number to it's object equivalent, call the .valueOf method, blah, blah, blah, does not make my answer wrong. If anything, it makes my answer thorough and complete. It shows the the person responding understands all that needs to occur, instead of being ignorant of the machine and how it works.

Comment: At the time I posted my comment, the information in your answer was irrelevant (rather than wrong) because the OP's issue isn't anything to do with the value being a string. The [*subtraction operator* `-`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-subtraction-operator-minus) calls *ToNumber* on the arguments, it doesn't even do a type check. There is no conversion to object, blah blah blah.

Comment: Oh yes, my friend. Primitive numbers are separate from their object counter parts. If you read any credible reference on JavaScript (say, the Definitive Guide), you will see that there is a sequence where a temporary object is created and, as you say, blah method is called, and the number value is returned. Those methods are not part of number primitives, no. They are methods of the temp object that is created.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<p>Calls a function to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius:</p>
<form>
input fahrenheit :<input type="number" id="fa"/>
<button onclick="toCelsius()">submit</button>
</form>

<script>
  function toCelsius() {
    var f = document.getElementById("fa").value;
    var result = (5/9) * (f-32);
    alert (result);
  }

</script>
```

Put the value check inside the function, with no parameters.

Comment: A correct answer, could do with a little more explanation though. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
var f = document.getElementById("fa").value;
```

This creates a global variable with the current value of the element with ID *fa*. It does not change after that, so regardless of what you enter into the form, you'll get the same value.

You need to get the value of the input when the button is clicked, so:

1. Change the button to type button so that it doesn't submit the form
2. Pass the current value to the function so that it get's the right value

E.g.

```js
function toCelsius(n) {
  var result = (5/9) * (n-32);
  alert (result);
}
```

```html
<p>calls a function to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius:</p>
<form>
  input fahrenheit :<input type="number" id="fa" name="fa">
  <button type="button" onclick="toCelsius(this.form.fa.value)">Calc value</button>
</form>
```

Note that the input must have a name to be successful (i.e. for its value to be submitted with the form). If you want the form to submit, set the button type back to submit (or remove the type since submit is the default).

Comment: Don't remove the type=submit for a button. In some circumstances (browsers, frameworks in play, etc), the <button> will not work as a submit unless you explicitly set it as such.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge—there is no framework in the OP. Button elements have been of type submit by default since they were introduced in [*HTML 4*](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40-971218/interact/forms.html#h-17.5) in 1997, almost 20 years ago. Which browsers are not compliant?

Answer (score -1):

You keep using

```
    var f = document.getElementById("fa").value;
```

You need to convert f to integer or float format so use ParseInt if you want only integers or ParseFloat if you want integers and fractions.

Comment: You don't know that the value of 'fa' will be an integer (so to speak).

Comment: True, ParseFloat should be used if you want 'f' to be a fraction.